# Testing if user can install fonts

Tags: c#, admin

I am making a screensaver application which uses a set list of fonts as so.

```
#region Fonts
        pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
        foreach (byte[] fbs in new byte[][] 
        {
          Resources.Amputa_Bangiz,
          Resources.AunchantedXspace, 
          Resources.Digitall,
          Resources.isocp2_IV25,
          Resources.radio1875_Bold, 
        })

        {


            IntPtr fontPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fbs.Length);

            Marshal.Copy(fbs, 0, fontPtr, fbs.Length);

            pfc.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, fbs.Length);


            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontPtr);
        }
#endregion
```

These fonts are built into the resources and so far i believe they are installed correctly so they don't need to be installed on the users computer. However, when run on a user limited computer such as a work computer with no admin privileges the private font collection only returns a generic font. Is there a way to not test for admin privileges but to test for the ability to install fonts. Also is the problem I described caused by this or another problem? Thanks.

Comment: Rocket science programming that nobody ever likes to do correctly.  You cannot call FreeCoTaskmem() until *after* you called the PrivateFontCollection.Dispose() method.

Comment: So can you provide an alternative possibly?

Comment: I did, nobody ever likes to hear it either.